# How can I write the output from a function to a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv, simulator, read.csv

I have a class that returns report object

```
class Report():
    def __init__(self, reporter, x, y, lane, event):
        self.reporter = reporter
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.lane = lane        
        self.time = int(time.time()) # current time in seconds
        self.event = event
```

The code to print the report object is as follows:

```
report_queue = []
def process_reports(self)
    for idx, report in enumerate(self.report_queue):
                print(report.x, report.y, report.lane, report.time, report.event)
```

The above code will print the data in console.[output result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS4B7.png) How can I save the result to a csv file ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def writecsv(Report,filename):
    delim = ","
    writestring = report.x + delim + report.y + delim + report.lane + delim + report.time + delim + report.event
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(writestring)

rep = Report()
filename = "test.csv"
writecsv(rep,filename)
```

There are also specific csv libraries for more complicated cases, but here I think you can just do it manually equally fast, since you're only doing a short file apparently.

Comment: writestring = report.x + delim + report.y + delim + report.lane + delim + report.time + delim + report.event
I am getting the following error message.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: One of the variables in Report() that you're adding to the string is not a string. Just put all of the report variables in a str(), e.g. str(report.time), so they will be converted to strings.